# Passing data from CollectionView to DetailVC in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

My `CollectionView` should pass a class model to `DetailViewController`, but when I tap on a cell I get the nil error.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value

The `CollectionViewController` is embedded programmatically on a `TabBarController`.

**Collection View**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return soundArray.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SoundCell", for: indexPath) as? SoundCell {
    let SoundClass = soundArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.updateUI(SoundClass: SoundClass)
    return cell

    } else {
    return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguetosound", sender: self)

  }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "seguetosound" {
    if let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailSecondVC
    let sound = sender as? SoundClass { 
    detailVC.SoundClass = sound 

    }
 }
```

**Detail View Controller**

```
class DetailSecondVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

private var _SoundClass: SoundClass!

var SoundClass: SoundClass {
        get {
            return _SoundClass
        } set {
            _SoundClass = newValue
        }
    }
```

Do you know what I am missing here? I tested the segue with a simple white screen and it works but when I try to pass the data, it fails.

Comment: Show cellForItem method

Comment: ok! i updated it

Comment: Makes perfect sense. You say `sender: self`. Then later you say `let sound = sender as? SoundClass`. So if `self` is not a SoundClass, `sound` will be `nil`. But `self` is not a SoundClass; it is a CollectionViewController.

Comment: And please, stop giving variables names that start with a capital letter. That's just wrong. And don't call a variable `SoundClass` or even `soundClass`. It is a variable, not a class. And you cannot “pass a class”.

Comment: @matt so who should be the sender? I changed the variable names but that didn't fix the problem ;)

Comment: make sure you are using the same identifier: "seguetosound"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited: I thought the solution was to make the segue from the view controller instead of from the cell, but as matt said, the segue was correct from the cell but I just had to remove the implementation of **didSelectItemAt**

Comment: Having the segue from the cell was right. What was wrong was, in that case, you must not trigger the segue in `didSelectItemAt`, because now you are triggering the segue _twice_. In fact you should leave the segue as it was and just delete your implementation of `didSelectItemAt`.

Comment: Got it, so the problem was that i was doing the segue twice! Thank you so much! I will edit my comment

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is this. First, figure out how you want to trigger the segue. One option is, in `didSelect`, trigger the segue in code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguetosound", sender: self)
}
```

But even better, just delete `didSelectItemAt` completely and have the segue in the storyboard come from the cell. That way the segue is triggered automatically when the user taps the cell.

Then, in `prepare`, find out what index path was selected, and pull out the data from the model and pass it to the destination view controller (this might not compile, because your variable names are so atrocious that I can't read your code, but it is the correct approach generally):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSecondVC" {
        if let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailSecondVC {
            if let paths = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                let row = paths[0].row
                detailVC.SoundClass = SoundClasss[row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but when I tap on the cell I still get the same error, and the variable is nil. Is not passed. Sorry about the variable names, they are the result of so many trial and errors

Comment: Well, I just tried this in my own project and it works, so probably something else is wrong that you're not telling us about.

Comment: thank you, yes, it seems is something else. I will find out

Comment: Thank you @matt, it is solved now, I will remember this post every time I name my variables