# Variable is empty inside of prepareforsegue function

Tags: ios, swift

I have data that I want to send to another view controller via a segue. I add some user selected data to an array in my first view controller inside of 'didselectrow' for a tableview, and in 'prepareforsegue' I attempt to set the first element of that array equal to a variable in my second view controller. However, I get an 'index out of range error' telling me that the array is empty, and I am not sure why.

Here is the first viewcontroller:

```swift
var selectedStores = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedStores.append(stores[indexPath.row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showStoreDetailsSegue", sender: self)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("Prepare for segue called")
        if segue.identifier == "showStoreDetailsSegue" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! StoreDetailsViewController

            destinationVC.selectedStore = selectedStores[0]
        }
    }
```

Second viewcontroller (StoreDetailsViewController):

```swift
var selectedStore = String()
```

I have another viewcontroller doing the exact same thing, but the array is not empty inside the prepareforsegue function. I have the tableview cell connected to the secondviewcontroller through a segue called "showStoreDetailsSegue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the tableview cell connected to the secondviewcontroller through a segue called "showStoreDetailsSegue".

That’s the problem. You are performing the segue twice, and the first time is before `didSelect` is called.

One solution: Connect the segue from the view controller, not the cell.

Alternatively (and better), delete your `didSelect` implementation itself. You don’t really need `selectedStores`. Just use `prepare` to find out what the selection is, and go from there.

Comment: So the first time is from the cell connection in the storyboard then, correct? Are you saying to delete that? I need the segue identifier though.

Comment: Basically this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319257/passing-data-from-collectionview-to-detailvc-in-swift-4 yesterday and hundreds of others before that.